# Latex: \bibliographystyle{abbrv} order citations based on appearance

Tags: latex

I am using Latex's \bibliographystyle{abbrv} command for references. But the order of citations is not in the sequence they appear in the document. Is there anyway, I can get citations in the order they appear in my document using abbrv style?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the `biblatex` package?

Comment: Yes, I have this line: \usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex} as you suggested, but I get a new error when I try to print the references using this command: "\bibliographystyle{abbrv}". I get something like  \bibliographystyle invalid. Use the package option style instead. Thanks for your time and suggestions.

Comment: Thanks Serge for your suggestions! I finally was able to resolve this using: \usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none,style=trad-abbrv,citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `sorting=none` option disables sorting:

```latex
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
```

From the `biblatex` manual (Section 3.1.2.1 General):

> The sorting order of the bibliography. Unless stated otherwise, the
>   entries are sorted in ascending order. The following choices are 
>   available by default:
>
> - `nty` Sort by name, title, year.
> - `nyt` Sort by name, year, title.
> - `nyvt` Sort by name, year, volume, title.
> - `anyt` Sort by alphabetic label, name, year, title.
> - `anyvt` Sort by alphabetic label, name, year, volume, title.
> - `ynt` Sort by year, name, title.
> - `ydnt` Sort by year (descending), name, title.
> - **`none`** Do not sort at all. All entries are processed in citation order.
> - `debug` Sort by entry key. This is intended for debugging only.