# referencing latex document in order of appearance

Tags: latex, bibliography

Suppose I have an ordered bibliography list

```
\bibitem{1} biblio 1
\bibitem{2} biblio 2
\bibitem{3} biblio 3
```

and suppose the first line in my text refers to `biblio 3`. Is there a way to make the refs follows the order of appearance or am I suppose to reorder the whole `bibitems` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Latex: \bibliographystyle{abbrv} order citations based on appearance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972080/latex-bibliographystyleabbrv-order-citations-based-on-appearance)

Answer (score 1):

Your new friend is `bibtex` or `biblatex` (the second is my pref.). The automatic order of references is just the top of the ice berg.

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibtex

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex